# murmurd doesn't accept SuperUser password

Tags: debian-squeeze, mumble

just installed a mumble-server (murmurd) under Debian Squeeze. I set the SuperUser password using the `murmurd -subw <newpassword>` command, then restarted the service. When I try to connect as a normal user, all is fine. When I try to connect as the SuperUser, I get a box asking me to enter the password. However, whatever password I enter is not accepted. Can anybody provide any pointers?

And yes, I have read the FAQ and the manuals and about a dozen other google results, but none could help me so far.

Comment: maybe this will help: https://superuser.com/questions/656880/mumble-cant-log-in-as-superuser-for-the-first-time/1537962#1537962 good luck
eigenmaechtig

Answer (score 3):

After some chatting on the IRC channel for mumble, it turns out that the -ini option has to be used to identify the config file when setting the SuperUser password, since the default config file in murmurd is not the normal config file in Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set the SuperUser password involves running the following command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure mumble-server
```

This brings up a wizard that allows you to set several aspects of the mumble service, including the SuperUser password.

Answer (score 0):

using ubuntu 18.04 it still was a little tricky.

installing packet mumble-server, adding user and login as user worked fine, but login as SuperUser failed with certificate or password error.

my solution: start murmurd as sudo, declare -supw also as sudo AND -ini [path_to_ini] must be given

(in my case: /etc/mumble-server.ini, which was already recognized, eg. welcomemessage was displayed (after restarting whole machine))

good luck ((--: K

Answer (score 0):

[eigenmaechtig](https://superuser.com/a/1537964/565263)'s answer is right:
You can check which `.ini` is loaded using

`service mumble-server status` (in Ubuntu)

and then set the password providing the correct path, e.g.

`sudo murmurd -ini /etc/mumble-server.ini -supw <your-password>`