# Mumble - Can't log in as SuperUser for the first time

Tags: passwords, ssl-certificate, mumble

I am trying to set up a Mumble LAN server for my household. I have downloaded and installed Mumble and Murmur and set up murmur.ini but when I try to log in as SuperUser for the first time to configure my server, I get a box saying "Wrong certificate or password for registered user.".
I have never changed my certificate since installing, and I am very sure I am using the correct password. How can I fix this so I can log in as SuperUser?

Any help would be great, cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [murmurd doesn't accept SuperUser password](https://superuser.com/questions/353188/murmurd-doesnt-accept-superuser-password)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you *really* changed the password and use the right murmur profile. Notice that

> murmurd

and

> sudo murmurd

will create different profiles.

Answer (score 0):

The commands I used to solved the problem was this.

`sudo murmurd -supw <pw>`

`sudo murmurd -ini /etc/mumble-server.ini`

Substitue `<pw>` for whatever password you want to use as you login as user "SuperUser"

Answer (score -1):

using ubuntu 18.04 it still was a little tricky.

installing packet mumble-server, adding user and login as user worked fine, but login as SuperUser failed with above described error.

my solution: start murmurd as sudo, declare -supw also as sudo AND -ini [path_to_ini] must be given

(in my case: /etc/mumble-server.ini, which was already recognized, eg. welcomemessage was displayed (after restarting whole machine))

good luck
((--: K